# Can't reach my local server, is something wrong with the header?

Tags: javascript, server, localhost, chatbot

I want to fetch all the "nodeIds" for a specific "chatid", but I can't reach my local server.

Do I need to generate a token to get access to my local server or can you identify any other mistake? Thanks for helping.

```
const config = {
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  const fetchNodeId = async (chatid) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `https://localhost:4001/api/chatbots/${chatid}/nodeid`,
        //`https://mybot.uber.space/api/chatbots/${chatid}`
        //`https://sandbox.as.wiwi.uni-goettingen.de/teachr/chatbots/pin/${pin}`
        config
      );
```

Comment: `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` is supposed to be set as response header from the server.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer. Do I need a token instead?

Comment: No default token is required unless you have yourself written a logic for that. Also, by default, `localhost` protocol should be `http` and not `https`.

Comment: ok it works now, thank you!